# How to setting PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Auto SetLocations for External Configuration in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, placeholder

I'am confused how to set location for External Configuration,

based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html i do some external configuration but fail, Here is my code

```
package com.org.tre.myth.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Configuration
public class ExternalPropertyConfig {


@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

Resource[] resources = new Resource[ ] {
        new ClassPathResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties"), // i want this config used when i deploy it in dev
        new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/conf.properties") // i want this config used when in local test
};

properties.setLocations( resources );
properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
properties.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
return properties;
 }
}
```

it's always running on FileSystemResource, when i deploy, it doesn't wanna to read automatically from ClassPathResource when on dev.
My config actually have same content (dev&test), the different is just at the directory because my dev do some layering and i want the configuration automatically running without even made a profile for spring.

I'am sorry

UPDATE

Im using this

```
Resource[] resources = new Resource[ ] {
            new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties"),
            new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/conf.properties")
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this

```
Resource[] resources = new Resource[ ] {
            new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties"),
            new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/conf.properties")
    };
```